# Keeping date intervals from overlapping and consistent with trigger in Oracle +11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g

Assume that I have the following:

```
    CREATE TABLE test (
    id NUMBER(10)
    , valid_from DATE
    , valid_to DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, valid_from)
    );

    INSERT INTO test (id, valid_from) VALUES (1, '01/JAN/1900');
    INSERT INTO test (id, valid_from) VALUES (1, '01/JAN/1901');
    INSERT INTO test (id, valid_from) VALUES (1, '01/JAN/1902');
    INSERT INTO test (id, valid_from) VALUES (2, '01/JAN/1903');
```

Output:

```
            ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO 
    ---------- ---------- ---------
             1 01-JAN-01           
             1 01-JAN-02           
             2 01-JAN-03           
             1 01-JAN-00
```

Now I need a trigger that will keep VALID_TO field consistent with VALID_FROM like this:

```
            ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO 
    ---------- ---------- ---------
             1 01-JAN-00  01-JAN-01
             1 01-JAN-01  01-JAN-02
             1 01-JAN-02           
             2 01-JAN-03
```

I have a query that calculates the VALID_TO and checks whether there are any records that need to be updated:

```
    WITH original AS (        
        SELECT id,
               valid_from,
               valid_to, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from DESC) seq  
        FROM test
    ), should_be AS (
        SELECT df.id,
               df.valid_from AS VALID_FROM, 
               dt.valid_from AS VALID_TO
        FROM original df
        LEFT OUTER JOIN original dt ON (df.id = dt.id 
                                        AND df.seq = dt.seq + 1)
    ), update_req AS (
        SELECT
            should_be.*, 
            CASE WHEN original.VALID_TO = should_be.VALID_TO OR (original.VALID_TO IS NULL AND should_be.VALID_TO IS NULL) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END UPDATE_REQUIRED        
        FROM should_be 
        INNER JOIN original ON (should_be.id = original.id AND should_be.valid_from = original.valid_from)
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM update_req
    ORDER BY id, valid_from
```

Output:

```
            ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO  UPDATE_REQUIRED
    ---------- ---------- --------- ---------------
             1 01-JAN-00  01-JAN-01 Y              
             1 01-JAN-01  01-JAN-02 Y              
             1 01-JAN-02            N              
             2 01-JAN-03            N
```

I use this query in a trigger that makes sure the VALID_TO field is updated if it is wrong:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ID_COLLECTION_T AS TABLE OF NUMBER(10);

    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_test
    FOR DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON test REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

        l_changed_ids ID_COLLECTION_T := ID_COLLECTION_T(); -- initialize

        AFTER EACH ROW IS
        BEGIN
            -- Keep track of changed ids
            CASE
                WHEN INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN l_changed_ids.extend; l_changed_ids(l_changed_ids.last) := :NEW.id;
                WHEN DELETING OR UPDATING THEN l_changed_ids.extend; l_changed_ids(l_changed_ids.last) := :OLD.id; 
            END CASE;

        END
        AFTER EACH ROW;

        AFTER STATEMENT IS

            l_existing_inconsistencies VARCHAR2(1);

        BEGIN

            -- first we check whether the executed statement caused any VALID_TO inconsistencies
            WITH original AS (        
                SELECT id,
                       valid_from,
                       valid_to, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from DESC) seq  
                FROM test
            ), should_be AS (
                SELECT df.id,
                       df.valid_from AS VALID_FROM, 
                       dt.valid_from AS VALID_TO
                FROM original df
                LEFT OUTER JOIN original dt ON (df.id = dt.id 
                                                AND df.seq = dt.seq + 1)
            ), update_req AS (
                SELECT
                    should_be.*, 
                    CASE WHEN original.VALID_TO = should_be.VALID_TO OR (original.VALID_TO IS NULL AND should_be.VALID_TO IS NULL) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END UPDATE_REQUIRED        
                FROM should_be 
                INNER JOIN original ON (should_be.id = original.id AND should_be.valid_from = original.valid_from)
                WHERE original.id MEMBER OF l_changed_ids -- we ONLY (!) want to search for inconsistencies for modified ids
            )
            SELECT CASE WHEN 'Y' IN (SELECT UPDATE_REQUIRED FROM update_req) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
            INTO l_existing_inconsistencies
            FROM DUAL;

           -- If there are inconsistencies, then we update the table.
           IF l_existing_inconsistencies = 'Y' THEN 

                MERGE INTO test o
                USING (
                        WITH original AS (        
                            SELECT id,
                                   valid_from,
                                   valid_to, 
                                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from DESC) seq  
                            FROM test
                        ), should_be AS (
                            SELECT df.id,
                                   df.valid_from AS VALID_FROM, 
                                   dt.valid_from AS VALID_TO
                            FROM original df
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN original dt ON (df.id = dt.id 
                                                            AND df.seq = dt.seq + 1)
                        )
                        SELECT
                                should_be.*, 
                                CASE WHEN original.VALID_TO = should_be.VALID_TO OR (original.VALID_TO IS NULL AND should_be.VALID_TO IS NULL) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END UPDATE_REQUIRED        
                        FROM should_be 
                        INNER JOIN original ON (should_be.id = original.id AND should_be.valid_from = original.valid_from)
                        WHERE original.id MEMBER OF l_changed_ids -- we ONLY (!) want to search for inconsistencies for modified ids
                ) n
                ON (o.id = n.id AND o.valid_from = n.valid_from AND n.UPDATE_REQUIRED = 'Y')
                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.valid_to = n.valid_to;

            END IF;

        END
        AFTER STATEMENT;

    END trg_test;
```

Now the trigger keeps the data consistent for inserted/updated/deleted ids:

```
    INSERT INTO test (id, valid_from) VALUES (1, '01/JAN/1899');
```

Now we find in the test table the following:

```
            ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO 
    ---------- ---------- ---------
             1 01-JAN-99  01-JAN-00
             1 01-JAN-00  01-JAN-01
             1 01-JAN-01  01-JAN-02
             1 01-JAN-02           
             2 01-JAN-03
```

**The problem here is the MEMBER OF statement. It is causing full table scans for each of it's members**. 
In case of multi-update/insert statements, there are many potential ids changed, so the l_changed_ids collection is large.
I can not optimize the MEMBER OF:
http://www.puthranv.com/search/label/Oracle%20Dynamic%20IN%20List
http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=301

I have tried:

1. Casting the collection with TABLE() is quite slow for many single inserts/updates.
2. Updating inconsistent rows from within a loop is a bad idea because for n-bulk statements this could potentially reactivate the trigger n times recursively. But (!) using a loop is very fast because the index on id is used every time.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there an other trigger-approach for this.
2. The trigger must work for single and bulk update/delete/insert statements. So if there are inconsistencies, there might only one extra update statement be executed recursively.
3. The trigger locks the rows based on id. (This is a later requirement but might be interesting to think about it now.)

**UPDATE1: Some performance analysis on calculating the VALIT_TO date:**

```
    -- Original query on 5mil records:  40 sec
    WITH original AS (        
        SELECT id,
               valid_from,
               valid_to, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from DESC) seq  
        FROM test
    ), should_be AS (
        SELECT df.id,
               df.valid_from AS VALID_FROM, 
               dt.valid_from AS VALID_TO
        FROM original df
        LEFT OUTER JOIN original dt ON (df.id = dt.id 
                                        AND df.seq = dt.seq + 1)
                                       ) select * from should_be


    -- TommCatt suggestion on 5mil records:  65 sec
    with Date_List as (
      select  t1.ID, t1.Valid_from as From_Date, Min( t2.Valid_from ) as To_Date 
      from    test t1
      left join test t2
        on    t2.id = t1.id
        and   t2.valid_from > t1.valid_from
      group by t1.ID, t1.Valid_from
    )
    select  id, from_date, to_date
    from    Date_List     


    -- TommCatt suggestion on 5mil records for 12c: untested


    -- a_horse_with_no_name suggestion on 5mil records:  10 sec WINNER!!
    SELECT id,
           valid_from,
           LEAD(valid_from, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY valid_from ASC) valid_to
    FROM test
    -- EXEC Plan for the winner:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Id  | Operation        | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |              |  5106K|    63M| 22222   (1)| 00:04:27 |
    |   1 |  WINDOW BUFFER   |              |  5106K|    63M| 22222   (1)| 00:04:27 |
    |   2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN| SYS_C0011495 |  5106K|    63M| 22222   (1)| 00:04:27 |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

I happened to test MEMBER OF performance in SQL during KScope14 conference. I blogged a bit about the results:

http://dspsd.blogspot.dk/2014/06/member-of-comparison-of-plsql-and-sql.html

Try replacing MEMBER OF with using TABLE operator to "convert" the collection into a "temp table". Either something like this:

```
FROM should_be 
INNER JOIN original ON (should_be.id = original.id AND should_be.valid_from = original.valid_from)
INNER JOIN TABLE(l_changed_ids) chg ON (chg.column_value = original.id)
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
FROM should_be 
INNER JOIN original ON (should_be.id = original.id AND should_be.valid_from = original.valid_from)
WHERE original.id IN (select column_value from TABLE(l_changed_ids))
```

Might be useful for the optimizer if you have approximate ideas of the number of changed ids to add cardinality hint:

```
FROM should_be 
INNER JOIN original ON (should_be.id = original.id AND should_be.valid_from = original.valid_from)
WHERE original.id IN (select /*+ cardinality(42) */ column_value from TABLE(l_changed_ids))
```

The above is untested code just typed directly here - I hope you can get it to work :-)

---

Oh, sorry, I just read your update that you have tried TABLE operator and it was slow for you...

Comment: TABLE() it will be if everything else fails.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to trigger based is using a materialized view refresh on commit and a constraint on the materialized view. I have seen the method mentioned in some discussions and forums. An example and some discussion is given here:

http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/08/30/non-overlapping-dates-constraint/

I haven't tried it myself, but it might be worth looking into?

Comment: Indeed, but as far as I recall, this is to only make sure there are no overlaps. In my case, I am trying to calculate and materialize a field. Because the table has many millions of rows and the query to calculate valid_to is complex (partition by...) a fast refresh on the MV wouldn't be possible I think. But I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can model your way out of this very easily with performance that will rival any other plans. Certainly the maintenance will be hugely reduced. I use this technique myself with great results.

First of all, when you have a From/To set of fields like this, you set up what I call a Row Spanning Dependency. This is horrible from a data integrity standpoint. Every time you perform DML, you have to execute at least two statements. To insert a new valid date record, you have to locate the "current" record and update the "to_date" then issue the insert. Any update of either date can only be done with two update statements. And, as you can plainly see, maintaining the validity of the sequence of dates is an absolute nightmare.

The solution is rather simple really. Only have a "valid" or "Effective" date rather than a From_Date field. Drop the To_date field entirely. Now, let's stipulate that when an ID becomes valid on the date in the valid field, it remains valid until another row is entered with the same ID and a later date. The date field in the second row is the date that row becomes valid but it is also the point when the first row becomes invalid (or no longer effective -- a term I like better).

One insert. Done!

Overlaps and gaps thus become impossible. You don't even have to check for them. Impossible!

But you have people who will want to see "From" and "To" in their reports, right? That's fine. "From" and "To" are fine in result sets, they just stink to blazes as data. So here's how to get "From" and "To" from the data:

```
with
Date_List( id, from_date, to_date )as(
  select  t1.ID, t1.Valid as From_Date, Min( t2.Valid ) as To_Date 
  from    test t1
  left join test t2
    on    t2.id = t1.id
    and   t2.valid > t1.valid
  group by t1.ID, t1.Valid
)
select  id, from_date, to_date
from    Date_List
order by id, From_date desc;
```

In the cte you're joining PK to PK -- very fast. Outside the cte, you may have to join with the table again to get other data that I'm sure you omitted for clarity. This will still be fast as again you are joining on PK fields. When you get Oracle-12c, you can rewrite it like this:

```
select  t1.id, t1.valid as from_date, t2.valid as To_date -- t1.etc, ...
from    test t1
left join test t2
  on    t2.id = t1.id
  and   t2.valid =(
            select  Min( t3.valid )
            from    test t3
            where   t3.id = t1.id
                and t3.valid > t1.valid )
order by t1.id, t1.valid desc;
```

This looks in some ways even worse with a join and subquery. Timing tests, however, will show impressive results. But, even if adding a To_Date field physically in the table made for slightly better performance, remember what I said before: GAPS AND OVERLAPS ARE IMPOSSIBLE!!! You couldn't even screw it up if you tried. The worst you could conceivably do is enter the same date twice for the same ID, but as these define the PK, the system won't let you do that. Think of all the triggers, constraints and stored procedures you won't have to write (not to keep the dates synched anyway)!

Comment: Did you try using `lead()` inside the CTE to get the `to_date`? In my experience that is almost always faster than a self join.

Comment: @TommCatt Thank you for your post. I totally agree with you on "`dropping the valid_to and only using valid(_from)`" physically. But this is a DW with millions of history data and the technical lead insists (!!) on materializing the calculated `valid_to` field on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. You and @a_horse_with_no_name did give me some good leads for rewriting/optimizing my query. Thank you for that! When I have more data I will update my question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I did not find that when I tested, but now that I think about it, that was about 5 years ago. Maybe performance of analytics has been improved since then.
OP: why are you writing triggers on DW tables? Are you still doing live operations in a DW? At any rate, just because you have "TO" doesn't mean you have to use it. Build the materialized view from a self join or LEAD function, and just don't worry about the "TO" dates at all. Could some of date sequences then be inaccurate? Sure, but a database can do nothing about accuracy, only integrity. Integrity first.